# Unit testing coroutines runBlockingTest: This job has not completed yet

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

Please find below a function using a coroutine to replace callback :

```
override suspend fun signUp(authentication: Authentication): AuthenticationError {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(authentication.email, authentication.password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activityLifeCycleService.getActivity()) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    it.resume(AuthenticationError.SignUpSuccess)
                } else {
                    Log.w(this.javaClass.name, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                    it.resume(AuthenticationError.SignUpFail)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to unit testing this function. I am using Mockk :

```
  @Test
  fun `signup() must be delegated to createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`() = runBlockingTest {

      val listener = slot<OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>>()
      val authentication = mockk<Authentication> {
        every { email } returns "email"
        every { password } returns "pswd"
      }
      val task = mockk<Task<AuthResult>> {
        every { isSuccessful } returns true
      }

      every { auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("email", "pswd") } returns
          mockk {
            every { addOnCompleteListener(activity, capture(listener)) } returns mockk()
          }

    service.signUp(authentication)

      listener.captured.onComplete(task)
    }
```

Unfortunately this test failed due to the following exception : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet`

I tried to replace `runBlockingTest` with `runBlocking` but the test seems to wait in an infinite loop.

Can someone help me with this UT please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can replace runBlockingTest on runBlocking or try to use workarounds described here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1204

Answer (score 16):

As can be seen in [this](https://medium.com/@eyalg/testing-androidx-room-kotlin-coroutines-2d1faa3e674f) post:

> This exception usually means that some coroutines from your tests were scheduled outside the test scope (more specifically the test dispatcher).

Instead of performing this:

```
private val networkContext: CoroutineContext = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

private val sut = Foo(
  networkContext,
  someInteractor
)

fun `some test`() = runBlockingTest() {
  // given
  ...

  // when
  sut.foo()

  // then
  ...
}
```

Create a test scope passing test dispatcher:

```
private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)
private val networkContext: CoroutineContext = testDispatcher

private val sut = Foo(
  networkContext,
  someInteractor
)
```

Then in test perform `testScope.runBlockingTest`

```
fun `some test`() = testScope.runBlockingTest {
  ...
}
```

See also Craig Russell's [*"Unit Testing Coroutine Suspend Functions using TestCoroutineDispatcher"*](https://craigrussell.io/2019/11/unit-testing-coroutine-suspend-functions-using-testcoroutinedispatcher/)

Comment: Is this solution supposed to work with non-android projects also ? (JVM + Coroutines + JUnit)

Comment: @theapache64, haven't tried that personally, but cannot see why that shouldn't work. Have you stumbled on obstacle in a non-android project?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried and failed. Logically,it should work. but it isn't.

Comment: "Failed" is a bit broad term, what exactly didn't work. Maybe some error message?

Comment: It says `This job has not completed yet`, before implementing the solution, and it says the same after implementing the solution. (but it's working with Android)

Comment: Hmmmm, sounds interesting. Not sure how I can help there, sorry. But please drop a message here if you find out what was the issue.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but this was the approach that worked for me, that's why I posted it here. Obviously, that's not working for some specific cases (or working for some specific cases, not sure on this one).

Comment: TestCoroutineDispatcher is deprecated.

Answer (score 12):

In case of `Flow` testing:

- Don't use `flow.collect` directly inside `runBlockingTest`. It should be wrapped in `launch`
- Don't forget to cancel `TestCoroutineScope` in the end of a test. It will stop a `Flow` collecting.

Example:

```
class CoroutinesPlayground {

    private val job = Job()
    private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestScope(job + testDispatcher)

    @Test
    fun `play with coroutines here`() = testScope.runBlockingTest {

        val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

        launch {
            flow.collect { value ->
                println("Value: $value")
            }
        }

        launch {
            repeat(10) { value ->
                flow.emit(value)
                delay(1000)
            }
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the first useful answer for testing flows that actually helped. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use flow.collect directly inside runBlockingTest. It should be wrapped in launch <--- Could you explain why?

Comment: @ThaiPD otherwise, the collect will suspend entire method and you won't be able to cancel it in the end.

Comment: This worked for me. used runTest scope instead of runBlockingTest

Answer (score 7):

**This is not an official solution, so use it at your own risk.**

This is similar to what @azizbekian posted, but instead of calling `runBlocking`, you call `launch`.
As this is using [TestCoroutineDispatcher](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-test-coroutine-dispatcher/), any tasks scheduled to be run without delay are immediately executed. **This might not be suitable if you have several tasks running asynchronously.**

It might not be suitable for every case but I hope that it helps for simple cases.

You can also follow up on this issue here:

- https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1204

If you know how to solve this using the already existing `runBlockingTest` and `runBlocking`, please be so kind and share with the community.

```kotlin
class MyTest {
    private val dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(dispatcher)

    @Test
    fun myTest {
       val apiService = mockk<ApiService>()
       val repository = MyRepository(apiService)
       
       testScope.launch {
            repository.someSuspendedFunction()
       }
       
       verify { apiService.expectedFunctionToBeCalled() }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't replace runBlocking with Launch.  The tests can give false positives if the test finishes before the coroutine does. RunBlocking exists specifically to address this.

Comment: Hey, @RobertLiberatore, in this case, the `testScope` is using [TestCoroutineDispatcher](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-test-coroutine-dispatcher) as a dispatcher, and using this makes any task scheduled to be run without delay be executed immediately. I'm not using `runBlocking` and `runBlockingTest` because these just don't work for the case. If you have suggestions on how to make them work for this case please share them with the community.

Comment: Per [Android's best practices with coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices):

"Use the TestCoroutineDispatcher's runBlockingTest in the test body to wait for all coroutines that use that dispatcher to complete... As all the coroutines created by the classes under test use the same TestCoroutineDispatcher, and the test body waits for them to execute using runBlockingTest, your tests become deterministic and won't suffer from race conditions."

Maybe you're willing to ride without a helmet, but I personally consider it bad advice.

Comment: I don't think you got the point, or I wasn't clear. I'm aware that it is not the best way and I never said the opposite, but `runBlocking` or `runBlockingTest` just doesn't work *for this case*. I would love to keep with the best practices, that's why I asked you to share an alternative solution.
Using the same analogy, if the helmet that they provide for you to ride is too small for your head, so you have no choice but to go without it.
I'm looking forward to your solution for this issue following the best practices.

Comment: If you want to improve your answer, I suggest offering some sort of deeper explanation as to why runBlockingTest, runBlocking, and CoroutineTestDispatcher.runBockingTest don't work for OP's case, making your answer acceptable.

Comment: Final note: TestCoroutineDispatcher skips over coroutine delays, but it does *not* guarantee that tests finish deterministically, let alone "immediately".

Comment: I added a couple of more explanations in my answer.
You are assuming that not go to the ride is a possible solution, then the choice is easy.
I'm looking forward to your solution for this issue following the best practices.

Comment: This is still a bad answer for the question. I've had my say.

Comment: Also, for anyone reading this: Azizbekian's answer follows best practices, will work if you implement it correctly, and the test will be robust (i.e. will still be correct even if you change the working code under test).

Answer (score 6):

According to my understanding, this exception occurs when you are using a different dispatcher in your code inside the `runBlockingTest { }` block with the one that started `runBlockingTest { }`.

So in order to avoid this, you first have to make sure you [inject Dispatchers](https://craigrussell.io/2019/11/unit-testing-coroutine-suspend-functions-using-testcoroutinedispatcher/) in your code, instead of hardcoding it throughout your app. If you haven't done it, there's nowhere to begin because you cannot assign a test dispatcher to your test codes.

Then, in your `BaseUnitTest`, you should have something like this:

```kotlin
@get:Rule
val coroutineRule = CoroutineTestRule()
```

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class CoroutineTestRule(
    val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher() {

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
}
```

Next step really depends on how you do Depedency Injection. The main point is to make sure your test codes are using `coroutineRule.testDispatcher` after the injection.

Finally, call `runBlockingTest { }` from this testDispatcher:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `This should pass`() = coroutineRule.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
    //Your test code where dispatcher is injected
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an open issue for this problem: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1204

The solution is to use the CoroutineScope intead of the TestCoroutinScope until the issue is resolved, you can do by replacing

```
@Test
fun `signup() must be delegated to createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`() = 
runBlockingTest {
```

with

```
@Test
fun `signup() must be delegated to createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`() = 
runBlocking {
```

Answer (score 6):

None of these answers quite worked for my setup due to frequent changes in the coroutines API.

This specifically works using [version 1.6.0 of kotlin-coroutines-test](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-test), added as a `testImplementation` dependency.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `test my function causes flow emission`() = runTest {
        // calling this function will result in my flow emitting a value
        viewModel.myPublicFunction("1234")
        
        val job = launch {
            // Force my flow to update via collect invocation
            viewModel.myMemberFlow.collect()
        }
        // immediately cancel job
        job.cancel()

        assertEquals("1234", viewModel.myMemberFlow.value)
    }
```

Comment: I guess this is not the right approach.
It should be handled in natural way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any

> Channel

inside the launch, you must call to

> Channel.close()

Example code:

```
val channel = Channel<Success<Any>>()
val flow = channel.consumeAsFlow()
    
launch {
      channel.send(Success(Any()))
      channel.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`runBlockingTest` deprecated since `1.6.0` and replaced with [runTest](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test#runtest).

Comment: `runTest` is experimental still. So shouldn't be used in production code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap arch background executor with one that execute tasks synchronously. eg. For room suspend functions, live data etc.

You need the following [dependency](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/arch-core) for core testing

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
```

Then add the following at the top of test class

```
@get:Rule
val instantExecutor = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Explanations

> InstantTaskExecutorRule A JUnit Test Rule that swaps the background executor used by the
> Architecture Components with a different one which executes each task
> synchronously.
> You can use this rule for your host side tests that use Architecture
> Components

Comment: The question is about coroutines, not livedata

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1204#issuecomment-641760266) about fixing `runBlockingTest`, maybe it could help you too.

Add this dependency if you don't have it

`testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$versions.testCoreTesting"` (2.1.0)

Then in your test class declare InstantTaskExecutorRule rule:

```
@get:Rule
val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Comment: Who said that this is liveData?  You better check what is inside of this lib, before asking such comments

Comment: This Rule is for managing Executor( plain Java stuff)

Comment: Now it's not `liveDataRule` :P